# EKS - Load balancers pending - No events

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have a cluster on EKS, which environments are constantly being created and destroyed using helm, each under its own namespace and each creating its own LoadBalancer using `ingress-nginx`.

Today, out of nowhere, load balancers for new environment stopped being created, and they are stuck on Pending (one of them is pending for over 70 minutes now). Also, no events are available for those services so no hints at all regarding what the issue might be.

Also tried to run `kubectl cluster-info dump | grep LoadBalancer` but it returned no results.

Any clues what might be the issue? or some debugging hints?

**Edit:**
After ~90 minutes of outage, suddenly all load balancers just created and started running. Maybe some AWS outage? couldn't find anything on their healthcheck website.

Comment: Right now we won't see it and next time you should check [AWS Dashboard](https://status.aws.amazon.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I could think of

1. Possibly hit an account limit for number of load balancers?
2. Check that you have enough IP addresses available so that your LB is able to be provisioned one.
3. The load balancers are having difficulty registering targets on your EKS cluster.

Have you taken a look the AWS [document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-load-balancers-troubleshooting/) on trouble shooting EKS load balancer issues? First 2 of the points I mentioned are actually on this list.

Comment: thanks for putting this. I am aware of this article and also went through its steps. Few months back we've hit the account limits and increased it. So current limit is 200, and we have only about 70 on at the moment. Also, the previous time this was the issue, event saying that showed up.

After about 90 minutes of outage, all of a sudden all load balancers started at once, and now new load balancers are starting correctly. Can this we some kind of aws outage?